# Does 'Only' always trigger inversion?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Is every sentence that "Only" comes first inverted?

For example, which one is correct?
"Only after every person on Earth forgets me **am I** dead."
or "Only after every person on Earth forgets me **I am** dead".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'only' is these sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233898/what-is-only-is-these-sentences) I'd write an answer here. Only this conversational ('The reason I'm not doing' etc) usage of 'only' has already been covered. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/only) classes it as a conjunction meaning 'except that' in ... ‘he is still a young man, only he seems older because of his careworn expression’.

Comment: You already have examples in Edwin's comment of sentences starting with _only_ that do not trigger inversion. Perhaps you could make it clear that you are asking about the inversion of subject/verb in the main clause following a subordinate clause starting with "_only_ + a conjunction. E.g. : "_only after everyone..., only if everyone..., only when everyone..._ .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's no inversion mentioned in the linked-to post.

Comment: @Aucaria There's no inversion [after _only_]  in the linked-to post.  [Inversion or no inversion after 'only'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141872/inversion-or-no-inversion-after-only) also addresses the usage involved here, though is itself closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it is fair to assume that the OP is asking about that type of *only* which means *not apart from* or similar, and has a link to negation. Linking to a post about a separate type of *only* is not helpful for anyone.

Comment: I would use the future here: *Only after every person on Earth forgets will I be dead.* Inversion is required here.  You might consider *...truly dead.* The *truly* doesn't make you any "deader,"  of course, but puts focus on the implications/meaning of being dead.

Comment: @Araucaria Whether or not OP has other usages in mind, the phrasing invites the above response. The fuller answer may well help others. In any case, both usages have already been covered, and the question correctly closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's only correctly closed as a duplicate if linked to a question that will help readers searching for an answer to this question. The current situation is a hindrance to readers and goes against the general principles of SE.